# SQL Injection when use ContentProvider

Tags: android, sql-injection, android-contentprovider

I have developed an application and I also published it to google play. But it was rejected because it is using a content provider that contains a SQL Injection vulnerability.
I checked the provider java file and I don’t know how to fix it! This is the Contentprovider code:

[image]

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: does google play provide any more information that helps point out where the injection is?

Comment: If you concatenate SQL queries together anywhere, then yes.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protecting your code from SQL injection vulnerabilities when you use a QueryBuilder is tricky and subtle.

Briefly, you must make sure that your code and only your code controls the parts of the query like selection, projection, and sort order, which are used to build the final query. You must not allow any untrusted content to be used for parts of your query.

Here's an article about SQL injection in content providers, that gives examples of how untrusted content can cause SQL injection vulnerabilities, and goes into more detail specific to Android development:

https://solidgeargroup.com/sql-injection-in-content-providers-of-android-and-how-to-be-protected

The TL;DR of it is:

> - **Projection:** check if the fields to query (name, size, format in the example above) exist in the table we want to get the data from.
> - **Selection:** use query parameterized methods.